# NPM install taking too long after Vaadin 23 upgrade

Tags: vaadin, node-modules, npm-install, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 14 app which decided to upgrade to Vaadin 23 following the instructions given in Vaadin's website. The problem is that it is taking too long to execute `npm install` in order to download the node modules. I've been waiting an hour so far. I've tried removing some dependencies, cleaning npm cache, upgrading spring version, and nothing worked. How can I fix this problem so as I can get my node modules downloaded???

Comment: Did you use `mvn vaadin:clean-fronted` before running `mvn install`?

Comment: Yes... I've just tried it... the problems persists

Comment: Are you using the latest Vaadin 23 release?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?